# Why does QGIS 3.4 and higher create .tmp file instead of refresh editing layer after saving?

Tags: geojson, fields-attributes, qgis-3, editing, json

I downloaded QGIS 3.4.0 and try to save edits in .geojson file. I can save new objects, but not edits in attributes. Insted of it, QGIS creates .tmp file with my chаnges into the same folder with editing .geojson. To save my edits I had to copy the text of .tmp file and put it by hand in my .geojson. How to enforse QGIS 3.4.0 save changes in layer like it was in 3.2.3 and do not create .tmp files?

**UPD**: For further validation analysis I use .geojson in classic JSON tree-like structure, but QGIS - in his own structure stroke-by-stroke. And if I export my .geojson by QGIS, it saves the file in his structure and this new one could be edited and saved with no any .tmp files. So it looks like QGIS 3.4 cannot save edits if .geojson file has tree-like structure (unlike QGIS 3.2).

**UPD2**:Below parts of broken and working GeoJSONs

Broken:
[image: Broken GeoJSON]

Working:
[image: Working GeoJSON]

Comment: At first I thought that it depends on version (3.4.0 or 3.4.1), but the problem occurs in both versions.

Comment: Its the same for the current QGIS-LTR (2.18.26). I assume it's related to GDAL/OGR 2.3.2.

Comment: Save As, export to a new file does not appear to fix it for me (2.18.27, GDAL 2.4, Win 10). Can you post example of broken vs working json files @mikhukh?

Comment: @wildintellect Thank you for the comment, I add examples in question's description

Comment: There is a bug report on issues.qgis.org: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20760. The issue seems to occur on Windows only.

Comment: Same here, on windows 10, QGIS 3.8.1. I also found I have to close my QGIS project before renaming my copies of .tmp files, otherwise QGIS overwrites them with the original data when I close (with or without saving project).

Comment: Unfortunately the issue https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20760 is still not resolved( And I do not understand when it will be and how to force it

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and had to find a workaround.  If you have access to PostGIS, you can export a valid geojson with the following statement.  This can also be used to create a function in PostGIS.  You can edit postgis layers directly in QGIS and then export using the statement below:

```
copy (
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
  'type',     'FeatureCollection',
  'features', jsonb_agg(feature)
)
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         id,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::jsonb,
    'properties', to_jsonb(inputs) - 'id' - 'geom'
  ) AS feature
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM output_table
  ) inputs
) features
) to 'C:\temp\output.json';
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue has been solved, as QGIS 3.10 uses GDAL 3.0.2.[image]
But at the same time it removes from GeoJSON a row with projection (in case you edit and save a file in JSON tree-like structure, rather than QGIS one).
[image]

Comment: It appears that the row with projection are not specified in GeoJSON standart: "Note: the use of alternative coordinate reference systems was specified in [GJ2008], but it has been removed from this version of the specification" https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#page-12

Comment: Anyway most stable QGIS version 3.4 saves GeoJSONs correctly.